# php update the price on the same page of search results

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

I am new to php and sql. I want to ask a question about how to update the price in the same page of php search result. I need add an `input` and a `submit` button for updating the price of the books among the search results. Upon submission the new price of the book should be updated onto the database and re-displayed onto the same page.

Here is the existing code of search html page and result php page. The search result already can show on the page, but how do I update the price? After I click the button the page will show error You have not entered search details.  Please go back and try again. Please help me.

[image: Search page]

Search Page:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Book-O-Rama Catalog Search</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Book-O-Rama Catalog Search</h1>

  <form action="results.php" method="post">
    Choose Search Type:<br />
    <select name="searchtype">
      <option value="author">Author
      <option value="title">Title
      <option value="isbn">ISBN
    </select>
    <br />
    Enter Search Term:<br />
    <input name="searchterm" type="text" size="40">
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: Result page with submit button]

Update page:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Book-O-Rama Search Results</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Book-O-Rama Search Results</h1>
<?php
  // create short variable names
  $searchtype=$_POST['searchtype'];
  $searchterm=trim($_POST['searchterm']);

  if (!$searchtype || !$searchterm) {
     echo 'You have not entered search details.  Please go back and try again.';
     exit;
  }

  if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
    $searchtype = addslashes($searchtype);
    $searchterm = addslashes($searchterm);
  }

  @ $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'pf31ee', 'pf31ee', 'pf31ee');

  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
     echo 'Error: Could not connect to database.  Please try again later.';
     exit;
  }

  $query = "select * from books where ".$searchtype." like '%".$searchterm."%'";
  $result = $db->query($query);

  $num_results = $result->num_rows;

  echo "<p>Number of books found: ".$num_results."</p>";

  for ($i=0; $i <$num_results; $i++) {
     $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
     echo "<p><strong>".($i+1).". Title: ";
     echo htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($row['title']));
     echo "</strong><br />Author: ";
     echo stripslashes($row['author']);
     echo "<br />ISBN: ";
     echo stripslashes($row['isbn']);
     echo "<br />Price: ";
     echo stripslashes($row['price']);
     echo "</p>";
  }

  $result->free();
  $db->close();

?>

<form action="results.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update price">&nbsp;<input type="text" name="price" maxlength="7" size="7">
<input type="hidden" name="searchtype" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['searchtype']);?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="searchterm" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['searchterm']);?>" />
<?php
$updateprice=$_POST['price'];

@ $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'pf31ee', 'pf31ee', 'pf31ee');
mysql_select_db('books');

  $query1 = "UPDATE books SET price = ".$updateprice." WHERE ".$searchtype." like '%".$searchterm."%'";
  $result1 = $db->query($query1);
  $result->free();  
  $db->close();

?>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
create table customers
( customerid int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
  name char(50) not null,
  address char(100) not null,
  city char(30) not null
);

create table orders
( orderid int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
  customerid int unsigned not null,
  amount float(6,2),
  date date not null
);

create table books
(  isbn char(13) not null primary key,
   author char(50),
   title char(100),
   price float(4,2)
);

create table order_items
( orderid int unsigned not null,
  isbn char(13) not null,
  quantity tinyint unsigned,

  primary key (orderid, isbn)

);
create table book_reviews
(
  isbn char(13) not null primary key,
  review text
);
```

```html
use myuser;

insert into customers values
  (3, "Julie Smith", "25 Oak Street", "Airport West"),
  (4, "Alan Wong", "1/47 Haines Avenue", "Box Hill"),
  (5, "Michelle Arthur", "357 North Road", "Yarraville");

insert into orders values
  (NULL, 3, 69.98, "2007-04-02"),
  (NULL, 1, 49.99, "2007-04-15"),
  (NULL, 2, 74.98, "2007-04-19"),
  (NULL, 3, 24.99, "2007-05-01");

insert into books values
  ("0-672-31697-8", "Michael Morgan", "Java 2 for Professional Developers", 34.99),
  ("0-672-31745-1", "Thomas Down", "Installing Debian GNU/Linux", 24.99),
  ("0-672-31509-2", "Pruitt, et al.", "Teach Yourself GIMP in 24 Hours", 24.99),
  ("0-672-31769-9", "Thomas Schenk", "Caldera OpenLinux System Administration Unleashed", 49.99);

insert into order_items values
  (1, "0-672-31697-8", 2),
  (2, "0-672-31769-9", 1),
  (3, "0-672-31769-9", 1),
  (3, "0-672-31509-2", 1),
  (4, "0-672-31745-1", 3);

insert into book_reviews values
  ("0-672-31697-8", "Morgan's book is clearly written and goes well beyond most of the basic Java books out there.");
```

Comment: Create a `<form>` for each found book and create a form handler, where you can use `update`-query

Comment: then how to save the searchtype and searchterm value when i click the button, because after i click and reload the wesbite what I have typed in search page was lost. @chris85

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the search type and value in the update form as well. You can use hidden input fields for that.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Book-O-Rama Search Results</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Book-O-Rama Search Results</h1>
<?php
  // create short variable names
  $searchtype=$_POST['searchtype'];
  $searchterm=trim($_POST['searchterm']);

  if (!$searchtype || !$searchterm) {
     echo 'You have not entered search details.  Please go back and try again.';
     exit;
  }

  if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
    $searchtype = addslashes($searchtype);
    $searchterm = addslashes($searchterm);
  }

  @ $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'pf31ee', 'pf31ee', 'pf31ee');

  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
     echo 'Error: Could not connect to database.  Please try again later.';
     exit;
  }

  $query = "select * from books where ".$searchtype." like '%".$searchterm."%'";
  $result = $db->query($query);

  $num_results = $result->num_rows;

  echo "<p>Number of books found: ".$num_results."</p>";

  for ($i=0; $i <$num_results; $i++) {
     $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
     echo "<p><strong>".($i+1).". Title: ";
     echo htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($row['title']));
     echo "</strong><br />Author: ";
     echo stripslashes($row['author']);
     echo "<br />ISBN: ";
     echo stripslashes($row['isbn']);
     echo "<br />Price: ";
     echo stripslashes($row['price']);
     echo "</p>";
  }

  $result->free();
  $db->close();

?>
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update price">&nbsp;<input type="text" name="price" maxlength="7" size="7">
<input type="hidden" name="searchtype" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['searchtype']);?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="searchterm" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['searchterm']);?>" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This code also is open to SQL injections. You should use [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), and a whitelist for columns being passed in. The `addslashes` function is insufficient, per the manual:

> Please note that use of addslashes() for database parameter escaping can be cause of security issues on most databases.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have another problem, I try to connect the db again and update the price, but it does't work. $query = "UPDATE books SET price = ".$updateprice.", WHERE ".$searchtype." like '%".$searchterm."%'"; is that wrong?

Comment: Yes, you have a trailing comma, `SET price = ".$updateprice.",` <--. Please accept this answer if it resolves your issue. Should be `UPDATE books SET price = ".$updateprice." WHERE ".$searchtype." like '%".$searchterm."%'` again open to SQL injections though.

Comment: almost done. the only problem is why i need to click twice for the page to show the updated price? I have checked the server side, after first click the database already changed.

Comment: Well I answered your question already, these are subsequent questions approaching the http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem. My guess would be you are outputting before you run the update so although the update occurs it is after the page has generated. There is no `update` SQL here so I dont know exactly where/when that occurs.

Comment: Sorry about that. I have upload the latest code and sql also. I am very appreciate your help.

Comment: Move the update higher up in the page execution. So you select the updated price, not the price prior to the update.

Comment: I understand. I put the update before the select query, now problem solved. Thank you very much.